# Error when executing a jcuda program in eclipse

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jcuda

I'm new with **JCuda**. I try to write a simple example in *Eclipse* on *Linux*. I have this error, but I haven't understand what it means. Here the code:

```
 import jcuda.Pointer;
 import jcuda.runtime.JCuda;
 public class cudaTest {
 public static 
 void main(String[] args) {
    Pointer pointer = new Pointer();
    JCuda.cudaMalloc(pointer, 4);
    System.out.println("Pointer: " + pointer);
    JCuda.cudaFree(pointer);
 }
}
```

I add the *Jcuda.jar* from the Java Build Path, and edit the Native library location by selecting the extracted **JCuda** file. 
The error is:

```
Error while loading native library "JCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64" with base name "JCudaRuntime"
Operating system name: Linux
Architecture         : amd64
Architecture bit size: 64
Stack trace from the attempt to load the library as a resource:
java.lang.NullPointerException: No resource found with name '/lib/libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so'
    at jcuda.LibUtils.loadLibraryResource(LibUtils.java:151)
    at jcuda.LibUtils.loadLibrary(LibUtils.java:83)
    at jcuda.runtime.JCuda.initialize(JCuda.java:303)
    at jcuda.runtime.JCuda.<clinit>(JCuda.java:290)
    at cudaTest.main(cudaTest.java:8)
Stack trace from the attempt to load the library as a file:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/Faith/JCuda-All-0.4.2-bin-linux-x86_64/libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so: libcudart.so.4: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at jcuda.LibUtils.loadLibrary(LibUtils.java:94)
    at jcuda.runtime.JCuda.initialize(JCuda.java:303)
    at jcuda.runtime.JCuda.<clinit>(JCuda.java:290)
    at cudaTest.main(cudaTest.java:8)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load the native library
    at jcuda.LibUtils.loadLibrary(LibUtils.java:129)
    at jcuda.runtime.JCuda.initialize(JCuda.java:303)
    at jcuda.runtime.JCuda.<clinit>(JCuda.java:290)
    at cudaTest.main(cudaTest.java:8)
```

Could tou help me please, I'm really need the solution. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look for `libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so` file in your system, and make a symoblic link to `/lib/libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so` OR add the path of the directory where you find it to your ldconfig

Comment: Please can you tell me how I do that, this is the first time when I use linux and cuda. How I get this file ?

Comment: Use `find` to find a file from command like this `find / -name 'libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so' `

Comment: OK, but how to make a symbolic link to this file or add the path of the directory where I find it to the ldconfig ?

Comment: For symbolic link perform following `ln -s /lib/libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so <PATH_TO_FOUND_FILE>`, ignore for a while the `ldconfig` option. Let me know about the result after symbolic link creation

Comment: I write this command:  ln -s /lib/libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so </home/faith/JCuda-All-0.4.2-bin-linux-x86_64> but I have this error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token "newline". I'm sorry, but i'm newer with linux.

Comment: Remove `< ... >` brackets, its not a part of a legal command, it was a notation from me to you. Also you are not pointing to `.so` file. I.e. `ln -s /lib/libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so /home/faith/JCuda-All-0.4.2-bin-linux-x86_64/PUT_THE_SO_FILE_NAME_HERE`

Comment: ah sorry. Now I have this error: ln: Unable to create the symbolic link "/home/faith/JCuda-All-0.4.2-bin-linux-x86_64/libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so ': File exists

Comment: now you sorry me, I've fixed the parameters order you have to do it like this `ln -s /home/faith/JCuda-All-0.4.2-bin-linux-x86_64/PUT_THE_SO_FILE_NAME_HERE /lib/libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so `

Comment: OK, I do it but the same problem, when I execute my cude program in eclipse I have the same errors.

Comment: Are you sure the error message is the same, please recheck also copy paste here the listing of your `/lib/` directory filter out unnecessary things I'm interested only in `libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so` file

Comment: Yes it is tha same, I beleive that the problem is in the native library. I edit the native lbrary location to the JCuda-All-0.4.2-bin-linux-x86_64 file.                                                                                                          ls JCuda-All-0.4.2-bin-linux-x86_64/
CUDPP license.txt  jcusparse-0.4.2.jar              
jcublas-0.4.2.jar  libJCublas2-linux-x86_64.so     
jcuda-0.4.2.jar    libJCublas-linux-x86_64.so      
jcufft-0.4.2.jar   libJCudaRuntime-linux-x86_64.so      ......

Comment: Its unclear what you mean by "I edit the native lbrary location to the JCuda-All-0.4.2-bin-linux-x86_64 file."  ?

Comment: I ceated a project java and I went to the Java Build Path tree item and select the Libraries tab. Click Add External Jars, navigate to the extracted folder of jcuda, and pick jCuda-0.4.2.jar. With the Libraries tab still open, expand the tree for the jCuda-0.4.2.jar wich I added and I clicked on Native library location (none). Then I clicked the Edit button. I asked for a location. I Clicked External Folder and I chose the jcuda extracted folder. And I Clicked OK. THis procedure is it true?!

Comment: I found this site:http://forum.byte-welt.net/byte-welt-projekte-projects/swogl-jcuda-jocl/jcuda/2972-jcuda-faq-please-read-posting.html#post116058 , which speak about Type 1: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load native library, it mentionned that we can resolve it by adding an argument in EClipse, but I don't know what I must add in the VM Arguments?

Comment: sorry I need to go home, will try to help you out when I'm home

Comment: The error message seems to be of **Type 5** (according to the "Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé"). So you have to create a symbolic link to '/usr/lib/libcuda.so.1' in '/usr/lib/nvidia/libcuda.so.1' **OR** add '/usr/lib/nvidia' to your ldconfig. (Sorry, I don't really know what this *means* admittedly - I just added it to the FAQ because I found some hints on the web that this can be the solution when it says "cannot open shared object file" on linux (I'm mainly a Windows user)

Answer (score 1):

Copy the .so files to lib directory:

```
$ sudo cp *.so /lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible idea - is to give a try to my project called **Mavenized JCuda**
https://github.com/MysterionRise/mavenized-jcuda

It's specifically created for the purpose of not fighting against classpath and other problems. It's really easy to use it, all you need to do - is to put needed version of JCuda in **pom.xml**, then run *mvn clean package* and then *mvn exec:exec*.

Full HowTo is available on Github page. Feel free to ask me question about that or raise question about the project